# how to display datas from a single column from mysql php to multiple columns in datatables

Tags: php, mysql, datatables

I use datatables with php mysql and ajax to recover data in three columns but how to have the data they are ordered and not duplicated as in the image but I want them sorted by name
in the following order and not duplicated.
In the database i have only one column'noms'for retrieving the datats from single column.
How to do that?
[image]

[image]

this is html

```
 <thead>
        <tr>
     <th>id</th>
        <th>Name1</th>
  <th>Name2</th>
  <th>Name3</th> 
        </tr>
    </thead>

this is script

     <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#users').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "fetch.php"
    })
    });
    </script>
```

this is fetch.php

```
$columns = array(
     array( 'db' => 'id', 'dt' => 0 ),
     array( 'db' => 'noms',  'dt' => 1 ),
     array( 'db' => 'noms',  'dt' => 2 ),
     array( 'db' => 'noms',  'dt' => 3 )
 
 );
  
 $sql_details = array(
     'user' => 'root',
     'pass' => '',
     'db'   => '',
     'host' => 'localhost'
 );
  
 require( 'ssp.class.php' );
 echo json_encode(
     SSP::simple( $_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns )
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can break result array to many arrays by array_chunk() function:

```
Input : $input_array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
        array_chunk($input_array, 2);
Output : Array(
                [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => a
                    [1] => b
                )
                [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => c
                    [1] => d
                )
                [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => e
                )
            )

Input : $input_array = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
       array_chunk($input_array, 2, true)
Output :    Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => a
                    [1] => b
                )
                [1] => Array
                (
                    [2] => c
                    [3] => d
                )
                [2] => Array
                (
                    [4] => e
                )
            )
```

Comment: THANKS but not working